# Why is my entire batch script running as a SETLOCAL command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, wmic

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, the output is always the entire script, with an `Invalid parameter to setlocal` error! This is probably just a silly mistake, but it's making me crazy.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM Obtain username of logged in user
SET loggedinuser=%USERNAME%

REM Create temporary vbscript to obtain user OU
echo Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2 >temp.vbs
echo. >>temp.vbs
echo Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") >>temp.vbs
echo Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command") >>temp.vbs
echo objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject" >>temp.vbs
echo objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider" >>temp.vbs
echo Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection >>temp.vbs
echo. >>temp.vbs
echo objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000 >>temp.vbs
echo objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE >>temp.vbs
echo. >>temp.vbs
echo objCommand.CommandText = _ >>temp.vbs
echo    ^"SELECT distinguishedName FROM ^'LDAP://dc=test,dc=com^' ^" ^& _ >>temp.vbs
echo        "WHERE objectCategory='user' " ^& _ >>temp.vbs
echo            "AND sAMAccountName='!loggedinuser!'" >>temp.vbs
echo Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute >>temp.vbs
echo. >>temp.vbs
echo objRecordSet.MoveFirst >>temp.vbs
echo Do Until objRecordSet.EOF >>temp.vbs
echo     strDN = objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").Value >>temp.vbs
echo     arrPath = Split(strDN, ",") >>temp.vbs
echo    intLength = Len(arrPath(1)) >>temp.vbs
echo    intNameLength = intLength - 3 >>temp.vbs
echo    Wscript.Echo Right(arrPath(1), intNameLength) >>temp.vbs
echo    objRecordSet.MoveNext >>temp.vbs
echo Loop >>temp.vbs

REM Save backup of old printer list, just in case
echo Creating a backup list of current printers, please wait...
wmic printer list brief /format:csv > \\networkshare\userfiles\!loggedinuser!\oldprinterlist.txt
echo Backup list completed.

REM Set the OU variable by running the vbscript
echo Discovering your department...
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('cscript.exe /nologo temp.vbs') do @set OU=%%a
echo Adding printers for %OU%

REM Perform new printer install based on OU
if %OU%==MIS (
set printer1=Printer_1_Yo
set printer2=Printer_2_Yo
set printer3=Printer_3_Yo
echo Adding %printer1%, please wait...
wmic printer call addprinterconnection \\newprintserver\%printer1%
echo %printer1% added. Adding %printer2%, please wait...
wmic printer call addprinterconnection \\newprintserver\%printer2%
echo %printer2% added. Adding %printer3%, please wait...
wmic printer call addprinterconnection \\newprintserver\%printer3%
echo %printer3% added. All printers are ready to use!
)

REM Delete printers that were on job
echo Deleting old printers from testserver, please wait...
wmic printer where servername=\\\\testserver delete
echo Deletion complete.
echo. If you would like to add more printers, please visit the Printers page on the intranet.
echo. Press any key to close this window.
pause>temp.txt
del temp.txt
del temp.vbs
```

After further testing, it seems that the `wmic printer where` line doesn't work properly, and I will fix that soon (suggestions welcome)... but is that the cause of the entire script falling apart? I'm aware that the vbscript portion is a little odd, but I don't think that's the issue either. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: the only thing that comes to my mind is to check if the file is formatted in Windows style , but not Linux.

Comment: what is the output from `wmic printer get ServerName` ?

Comment: @npocmaka: The old and new printservers in some kind of order. `\\oldserver` `\\oldserver` `\\oldserver` `\\newserver` All separated by a line break.

Comment: then why in where query you use 4 slashes? I don't think you need escape sequence there.

Comment: It was listed that way in an example, so I left it by default. After testing, it seems even `wmic printer where servername=\\server list brief` displays the node (my local machine) and then gives an error - Invalid query.

Comment: try to set the server in double quotes or with `like` without slashes: `where "servername like someserver"`

Comment: @npocmaka That seems to be working without errors, however it results in "No Instance(s) Availible." I tried `"where servername like server"`, `"where servername like \\server"`, and `"where servername=\\server"`. I even tried this with the four slashes, just in case. My user has three printers on "server", so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: where should be outside the quotes...

Comment: If `where` is outside of the quotes, I recieve the Invalid query error yet again.

Comment: aaghhh. Sorry you also need to set the server in single quotes: `where "servername like 'someServer'"`

Comment: or `where "servername='\\someserver'"`

Comment: @npocmaka Yep, that was the issue regarding that printer command. However, still having any issue with SETLOCAL. Any more ideas as to what could be causing that?

Answer (score 1):

If your script does NOT start with `@ECHO OFF` command, then you will see in the screen the fully script contents when it runs.

I want to make good use of this post, so I modified your script in order to make the creation of the temp.vbs file much cleaner, although this point is not directly related to your problem. However, when I tested the Batch file below with a `GOTO :EOF` command inserted after the creation of the temp.vbs file, it correctly runs with no "setlocal" error!

**EDIT**: I realized that original script uses `loggedinuser` variable to hardcode its value in the creation of the temp.vbs program, that is the reason because the file is created and deleted each time. My original translation does not account for this detail.

I modified the Batch file below to pass the value of `loggedinuser` from Batch to VBS section *in the parameter*. This way, the .vbs program could be created just once with a more appropriate name.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM Obtain username of logged in user
SET loggedinuser=%USERNAME%

REM Create temporary vbscript to obtain user OU, if not exists
if not exist getUserOU.vbs (
   for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^:VBS_Section" "%~F0"') do set n=%%a
   more +!n! < "%~F0" > getUserOU.vbs
)

REM Save backup of old printer list, just in case
echo Creating a backup list of current printers, please wait...
wmic printer list brief /format:csv > 

\\networkshare\userfiles\!loggedinuser!\oldprinterlist.txt
echo Backup list completed.

REM Set the OU variable by running the vbscript
echo Discovering your department...
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('cscript.exe //nologo getUserOU.vbs "%loggedinuser%"') do @set OU=%%a
echo Adding printers for %OU%

REM Perform new printer install based on OU
if %OU%==MIS (
set printer1=Printer_1_Yo
set printer2=Printer_2_Yo
set printer3=Printer_3_Yo
echo Adding %printer1%, please wait...
wmic printer call addprinterconnection \\newprintserver\%printer1%
echo %printer1% added. Adding %printer2%, please wait...
wmic printer call addprinterconnection \\newprintserver\%printer2%
echo %printer2% added. Adding %printer3%, please wait...
wmic printer call addprinterconnection \\newprintserver\%printer3%
echo %printer3% added. All printers are ready to use!
)

REM Delete printers that were on job
echo Deleting old printers from testserver, please wait...
wmic printer where servername=\\\\testserver delete
echo Deletion complete.
echo. If you would like to add more printers, please visit the Printers page on the intranet.
echo. Press any key to close this window.
pause>temp.txt
del temp.txt

goto :EOF

:VBS_Section

Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000
objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

objCommand.CommandText = _
   "SELECT distinguishedName FROM 'LDAP://dc=test,dc=com' " & _
       "WHERE objectCategory='user' " & _
           "AND sAMAccountName='" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "'"
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

objRecordSet.MoveFirst
Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    strDN = objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
    arrPath = Split(strDN, ",")
   intLength = Len(arrPath(1))
   intNameLength = intLength - 3
   Wscript.Echo Right(arrPath(1), intNameLength)
   objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

For your wmic printer command use:

```
wmic printer where 'servername="\\\\testserver"'
```

If that doesn't work, swap the single and double quotes. I'm not at a computer atm, so I'm going from memory. Also, you don't have to go through all that creating vbscript to get a ou. Wmic can query ldap.

```
 WMIC /NAMESPACE:\\root\directory\ldap PATH ds_user  GET ds_distinguishedname
```

Here is my version of your script.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set q=wmic /NAMESPACE:\\root\directory\ldap PATH ds_user Where "ds_samaccountname^='!username!'" get ds_distinguishedname

for /f "skip=1 tokens=3 delims==" %%a in ('%q%') do (
   for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%b in ("%%a") do set ou=%%b
)

:: Save backup of old printer list, just in case
set share=\\networkshare\userfiles
if not exist "%share%\!username!" md "%share%\!username!"
set printlist="%share%\!username!\oldprinterlist.txt"
echo Creating a backup list of current printers, please wait...
wmic printer list brief /format:csv > %printlist%
echo Backup list completed.

::Perform new printer install based on OU
IF %ou%==MIS (
  call :addprinter Printer_1_Yo Testserver
  call :addprinter Printer_2_Yo Testserver
  call :addprinter Printer_3_Yo Testserver
)

::Delete printers that were on job
echo.
echo Deleting old printers from testserver, please wait...
wmic printer where "servername='\\\\testserver'" delete
echo Deletion complete.
echo.
echo. If you would like to add more printers, please visit the Printers page on the intranet.
echo. Press any key to close this window.
pause>nul  
goto :eof

:addprinter prn server
echo.
echo Adding %1, please wait...
wmic printer call addprinterconnection \\%2\%1
```

Comment: That wmic printer command does indeed work. However, I'm still having the same issue with everything running through SETLOCAL.
Additionally, that wmic command just gives me the entire list of AD users and their OU - yikes! I'm sure there's a way I can tone it down, but one thing I like about the vbscript is how the output is simply the OU without the `OU=` tacked on.

Comment: It's trivial to get just the ou for a particular user with wmic and it's only a few lines of code. I'll show you tomorrow when I get to work.